# Maximum Distance in Arrays | Competitive coding question

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Question Statement -

Given m arrays, and each array is sorted in ascending order. Now you can pick up two integers from two different arrays (each array picks one) and calculate the distance. We define the distance between two integers a and b to be their absolute difference |a-b|. Your task is to find the maximum distance.

Example -

```
Input: 
[[1,2,3],
 [4,5],
 [1,2,3]]
Output: 4
```

My Approach - Since, the arrays are sorted, in the final answer, one element will be from first index of the arrays, and other element will be from the last index of the arrays. So, I am able to device a brute-force solution, To get to the answer. Basically I am generating *all possible combinations of Last Element of One Array and First Element of other.* This is giving me TC of O(n^2).
How can I optimize my approach. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly observe, only the minimum and maximum elements of arrays are of any interest. You can find the minimum of `n` sorted arrays in `O(n)`, the maximum in `O(n)`, and the answer appears to be `max - min`, which is `O(1)`.

The problem is harder if we do not allow the max and min to belong to the *same* array. In that case, a brute-force solution (taking all min-max combinations into account) would again require `O(n^2)` computation. But you can do better:

- build a 2-d array `m` such that `m[i][0] = min(array[i])` and `m[i][1] = i`; sort it ascending so that `m[j][0] <= m[j+1][0]` (cost: `O(n log n)`)
- build another 2-d array `M` with `M[i][0] = max(array[i])` and `m[i][1] = i`; sort it descending so that `m[j][0] >= m[j+1][0]` (cost: `O(n log n)`)
- check whether `m[0][1] != M[0][1]`,

  - if true, you can safely return is `M[0][0] - m[0][0]`
  - otherwise, the result will be `max(M[0][0] - m[1][0], M[1][0] - m[0][0])`

You can avoid fully sorting `m` and `M` by keeping track of largest, second-largest, smallest, and second-smallest elements, as well as their array indices (with an improved cost of `O(n)`) - but when programming in contests, simple-and-optimal-enough is often better than really-optimal-but-tricky-to-write.

Answer (score 2):

It's very straightforward.

- Maintain minimum variable which has the minimal value of all lists.
- Before *including current minimum*, calculate the diff of current minimum with current list's maximum.
- Do step 2 from first to last and from last to first.
- This way you will account for all possibilities of min and max without having to generate or calculate for each one of them.

**Snippet:**

```
public int maxDistance(List<List<Integer>> arrays) {
        int max_diff = 0,min = arrays.get(0).get(0);
        
        for(int i=1;i<arrays.size();++i){
            List<Integer> curr = arrays.get(i);
            max_diff = Math.max(max_diff,Math.abs(curr.get(curr.size()-1) - min));
            min = Math.min(min,curr.get(0)); // take min afterwards
        }
        
        min = arrays.get(arrays.size()-1).get(0);
        
        for(int i=arrays.size()-2;i>=0;--i){
            List<Integer> curr = arrays.get(i);
            max_diff = Math.max(max_diff,Math.abs(curr.get(curr.size()-1) - min));
            min = Math.min(min,curr.get(0));  // take min afterwards
        }
        
        return max_diff;
    }
```

- Time complexity: O(n), Space complexity: O(1).

Comment: Interesting!, need to add a condition , that the other value (max) should not be from the same list

Comment: @shaileshbhagat, the part of the algorithm that is stressed with *italics* ensures that the values that contribute to the difference will not be from the same list.

Comment: @shaileshbhagat Agreed with trincot.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in linear time:

- Find the two arrays which have the overall least two values. For this you need to scan once the first values of all the input arrays. Let's call those two arrays A and B, where A[0] <= B[0] and B[0] <= all X[0], where X != A
- Find the two arrays which have the overall greatest two values. For this you need to scan once the last values of all the input arrays. Let's call those two arrays C and D, where C[last] >= D[last] and D[last] >= all X[last], where X != C
- If A != C, then return C[last] - A[0]
- Else, the greatest of the following two expressions: D[last] - A[0] and C[last] - B[0]

Implementation in JavaScript:

```js
function solve(arrays) {
    if (arrays.length < 2) throw "must have at least 2 arrays";
    let a, b, c, d;
    for (let row of arrays) { // collect two least and two greatest
        let low = row[0], high = row[row.length-1];
        if (!a || low < a[0]) [a, b] = [row, a];
        else if (!b || low < b[0]) b = row;
        if (!c || high > c[c.length-1]) [c, d] = [row, c];
        else if (!d || high > d[d.length-1]) d = row;
    }
    return a !== c ? c[c.length-1] - a[0]
          : Math.max(c[c.length-1] - b[0],
                     d[d.length-1] - a[0]);
}

let res = solve([[1,2,3],[4,5],[1,2,3]]);
console.log(res);  // 4
```